# How to limit Wikipedia pageview API results to maximum 10 or 20?

Tags: api, wikipedia

Wikipedia provides an API to view the top articles for a day, for example [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikipedia/all-access/2018/01/29).

This results in top 1000 articles on date January 29, 2018. However, the problem is that it gives a thousand articles by default and I can't find a string to limit result to max 50.

How can I limit the response to max 50?

Answer (score 0):

While [the API does not offer this functionality](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/AQS/Pageviews), you could easily shorten the list yourself. This is also how [this Python API for the Pageviews API](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwviews) implements a *limit* on the number of returned pages.